# send tidy json data of a database model from server(python) to client

Tags: javascript, python, json, google-app-engine, serialization

I am using appengine, webapp2 framework. 
I have the following model:

```
class Match(db.Model):
    date_time = db.DateTimeProperty()
    team1 = db.StringProperty()
    team2 = db.StringProperty()
    venue = db.StringProperty()
    result = db.IntegerProperty()
```

Now on the client side, an event makes a post request to one of my `views`, based on that post request, i want to send json data which easily readable by jQuery/javascript.

What would be the best way of doing it?

Comment: Are you asking how to do the request as well?

Comment: No, i just wanted to know, how to process the data of a model in a view and return json objects which can be read on the client side.

Comment: Ok. As far as processing on the client-side, i think if you return a json string as type "application/json" it will already be a json object in javascript.

Comment: What does the view and JSON have to do with the model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the models:

```
class DictModel(db.Model):
    def to_dict(self):
       return dict([(p, unicode(getattr(self, p))) for p in self.properties()])


class Match(DictModel):
    date_time = db.DateTimeProperty()
    team1 = db.StringProperty()
    team2 = db.StringProperty()
    venue = db.StringProperty()
    result = db.IntegerProperty()
```

and in the views:

```
import json
self.response.out.write(json.dumps([m.to_dict() for m in matches]))
```

Comment: If he's using webapp2, he's probably using python27 on AppEngine, which means he can use the better json library than the simplejson one. import json instead.

Comment: Nice. I was having some problems and this worked perfectly. I added the to_dict() as well as a to_json() method to my base model class. That made my life a hell of a lot easier.

Answer (score -1):

First of all i woul recommend using guido`s ndb instead of the old db module. But actually both the old db module and ndb has a solution for you. First you need to convert your model from an object to a json serializable structure. Specifically a python dictionary.

Old db

dict = db.to_dict(Matchentity)

ndb

dict = Matchentity.to_dict()

Now you have to serialize this into json, and this isnt as trivial as you might think, since there are some properties that you have to handle, since their values wont make much sense in json. In new ndb you can simply exclude these by using exlude parameter in the to_dict() method and in the old db it might be a better idea to write a specific method for each model. Then use json.dump(dict) there are some good discussions about this on the ndb mailing list.